# Not able to create pytorch cpu image on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tpu

I am trying to create a preemptible tpu instance on GCP using the following command

```
gcloud compute instances create tpu-1-vm \
  --image-project=deep-learning-platform-release \
  --image-family=pytorch-latest-cpu\
  --preemptible \
--zone=us-central1-f
```

These command crashes with following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Required 'compute.images.useReadOnly' permission for 'projects/deep-learning-platform-release'
```

The error is obvious that I don't have permission to read that image. What is want to know is how to get access to these images? It should be possible as this command is copied almost verbatim from gcp documentation [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/pytorch_start_instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue with your command is a small typo in the `image-project` field. The correct `image-project` is `deeplearning-platform-release` and not `deep-learning-platform-release`. So the following command should work without an issue:

```
gcloud compute instances create tpu-1-vm \
  --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
  --image-family=pytorch-latest-cpu \
  --preemptible \
  --zone=us-central1-f
```

Comment: I am so embarassed! Thank you